# Solution for URL issues

Tags: joomla

CMS
Joomla

I have created two seperate pages for an old Joomla 1:0 system 
**The seo friendly option is unavailable** and for various reasons I cant touch/update the joomla system

The chief executive wants to create a newletter with a specific url
So Firstly I need to create this subdomain
www.mydomain.co.uk/mysports to measure the success rate of the mail campaign

I also need to link that subdomain domain to the content page below
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=159&Itemid=278

What would you say are the best options for doing this in Joomla

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. when you say "sub-domain" you probably mean "folder" or "sub-folder", not [sub-domain](http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/webdesign/what-is-a-subdomain-how-to-create-a-subdomain/).
2. if I'm correct about assumption #1 then what you want to do is easy: create a folder "mysports" under Joomla home. inside this folder create the following php file (call it "index.php"):

   < ?php
   header("Location: http://www.mydomain.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=159&Itemid=278");
   ?>

and you're good to go.